# Where can I find the Caller ID settings on BQ version of Android N?

Tags: 7.1-nougat, caller-id

I have a BQ Aquaris U, which I have upgraded to Android 7.1.1, but now when I call somebody, my number is private. I cannot find where the related setting is moved. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

After hours of searching among the settings:
Phone -> More options (three dots) -> Settings -> Calling Accounts -> SIM -> Additional Settings and voila, there it is :).

Comment: I don't have the same options. It appears that this solution is specific to the phone model.

Comment: @ale Or rather, the Phone app in use.

Comment: Yes, I believe that only applies to BQ version of Android.

Comment: it is there, but it's greyed out. what the heck?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the phone dialling pad screen. Then go into the 3 little dots top right of screen. Select 'Settings', then 'More Settings' and in there you'll find the setting you're looking for.

Comment: nope, there is no caller id there (8.0)